# Class function as array value

Tags: php

i want to place an class function as array value, but it shows parsing error:

- Linter error message - Expecting `']"
- Php error message -
  ErrorException [ Parsing Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '['

  Example

  'name' => [
      'data_type' => 'varchar',
      'label' => Lang::get('site.general.name'),
  ...

As you see, i want the label to be the value returned from the "lang" class "get" function.

Comment: the error is a lack of closing square brace, exactly what it says!!

Comment: Perhaps you're using version below 5.4 in which short array definition via `[]` was allowed

Comment: Could you paste the entire array structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array short syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) [i.e. `$a = ['a', 'b']`] is available from version 5.4 on.

Be sure to have the right PHP version to use it, otherwise you should stick to old `array('a', 'b')` syntax.

Comment: Changed back to "array()" from "[]", but still, Lang::get(..) gets parsing problems.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on key `name` line.
Try syntax like this:

```
$array = array(
   'name' => 'val',
   'data_type' => 'varchar',
   'label' => Lang::get('site.general.name'),
   'array' => array(
      ...
   )
);
```

And be sure that Lang::get('site.general.name') return a value.

Answer (score -1):

Change [ to `array(` like this:

```
'name' => array(
  'data_type' => 'varchar',
  'label' => Lang::get('site.general.name'),
```

`[]` for defining arrays isn't supported in older versions.

Comment: Shouldn't we ask the PHP version that is being used before make any assumptions ?

Comment: I don't think there are any possible reason for this behaviour. As I see the others have the same opinion.

Comment: And none answered correctly. He did try to change to the old syntax without success. I really think it is something wrong with the array structure rather then PHP version.

Comment: Actually you miss that the error changed. So the first problem was caused by the old php version. It is true that there are other issues also, but it is a second issue.